# "Cannot used in global ORDER clause" with mysql ordering

Tags: mysql

I have problem with this SQL query:

```
(SELECT tb1.id,tb1.bdate,tb1.jumpCard,tb1.publicImage,tb1.lastlogin
FROM users AS tb1, online AS tb2
WHERE tb1.valid='1' AND tb1.sex='female' AND tb1.looking_for='male' AND tb1.id = tb2.member_id
ORDER BY tb1.publicImage) ORDER BY tb1.id DESC
```

for some reason I'm getting:

```
Table 'tb1' from one of the SELECTs cannot be used in global ORDER clause
```

any advice?

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The reason it doesn't work is the outer `ORDER BY` can't "see" tb1 - it sees the results of the inner subquery. So in a syntactically correct version of your query, you would simply `ORDER BY id` :

```
(SELECT tb1.id,tb1.bdate,tb1.jumpCard,tb1.publicImage,tb1.lastlogin
FROM users AS tb1, online AS tb2
WHERE tb1.valid='1' AND tb1.sex='female' AND tb1.looking_for='male' AND tb1.id = tb2.member_id
ORDER BY tb1.publicImage) ORDER BY id DESC
```

But, as others are pointing out, this can more simply written as a single query ordered by id

Comment: You've save my life

Answer (score 3):

If you put parentheses around your `select` then the inner table will not be visible outside

```
SELECT tb1.id,tb1.bdate,tb1.jumpCard,tb1.publicImage,tb1.lastlogin
FROM users AS tb1, online AS tb2
WHERE tb1.valid='1' AND tb1.sex='female' AND tb1.looking_for='male' AND tb1.id = tb2.member_id
ORDER BY tb1.publicImage, tb1.id DESC
```

And you can specify multiple columns in one `order by` clause

Answer (score 2):

When you close your parentheses after select statement, your second `order by` clause becomes invalid. Instead try merging your order by columns in a single `order by` statement like the following:

```
SELECT tb1.id,tb1.bdate,tb1.jumpCard,tb1.publicImage,tb1.lastlogin
FROM users AS tb1, online AS tb2
WHERE tb1.valid='1' AND tb1.sex='female' AND tb1.looking_for='male' AND tb1.id = tb2.member_id
ORDER BY tb1.publicImage, tb1.id DESC
```